# Win8 App doesn't open after 20 times then fails with: Not enough quota is available to process this command. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070718)

Tags: windows-runtime

Hi this is my 1st question asked:

I've got a WinRT app (C#/XAML) that opens fine the first 20 times then fails to open after that.

In the windows event application log the (unhelpful) message is that "App did not launch within its allotted time". If I attach Visual Studio debugger, it looks like the underlying error is "Not enough quota is available to process this command. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070718)".

Edit: it looks like it may be a problem with bg agent duplicate registration... will update

Comment: I am not sure if this is applicable in your case but a [Bing Search](http://www.bing.com/search?q=HRESULT%3A+0x80070718&qs=n&form=QBLH&pq=hresult%3A+0x80070718&sc=0-0&sp=-1&sk=) led to [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/d778c6e0-c248-4a1a-9391-28d038247578)

Comment: Thanks Mark, checked hat out already, think it is something different in my case, just investigating if it's something to do with background agent...

Comment: Expecting people to install your app to try and figure out what the problem is is unreasonable, IMO. You've posted no info about your app, no code, and a generic error message without a stack trace or any other useful information. Without any information other than "You can install my app to try and figure out what my problem is", I'd think this question should be closed as "too localized"; if your problem isn't in the question, and requires a download and install from an off-site location, it's totally meaningless if that off-site link is unavailable and not searchable by later readers here.

Comment: Hi Ken, thanks for taking the time to reply, I agree a stack trace would be helpful, i will post one shortly.

Answer (score 3):

The underlying "Not enough quota is available to process this command. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070718)" message was being caused by:

```
BackgroundAccessStatus status = await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();
```

being called on every load of the app. The 21st load and subsequent loads would all fail with "App did not launch within its allotted time" appear in application event log.

Making the call only happen only the first time a user loads the app has fixed the problem, the app now opens 30+ times with no error.

Comment: +1. Thanks for posting the solution so that others can use it in the future. :-)